# Cookies are not retained when IE is restarted

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I tried a sample web application to store cookies and retrieve them.

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)Executions.getCurrent().getNativeResponse();
Cookie [] cookies = ((HttpServletRequest)Executions.getCurrent().getNativeRequest()).getCookies();
```

I added some cookies to the response and I am able to retrieve them.

I am using IE8 and there are two scenarios -

1. I have one IE browser open (assume A). I launched the application in another IE browser(assume B) and set cookie values. Now I close B and open one (another assume C) and I am able to retrieve values from Cookie since A is still open.
   It is working good.
2. If I open a new browser (assume A) set cookies now. I close A and open one another (assume B). Here I am unable to retrieve values from cookie since no other browser is open...

Looking for suggestions to solve this to retrieve values all the times irrespective of browsers open/closed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, cookies expire when the session (typically the browser's window) expires.

You need to set an expiration date in the future. Presumably with `setMaxAge()`:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-cookies-handling.htm

Comment: Denis, Your solution is working... Thank you. I tried this earlier in my application and it didnt work at that time... Now it works in sample I tried and in the application too. Many Thanks